# R Regression Loop

Tags: r

I am attempting to write an R script that will run through a regression for every 1000 rows of data.

I would also like to store the output into a csv file.

Data Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-W2Dyw4QjoMQ0F1ZFhsdWJORHM

Any help would be great!

```
 z <- read.csv("Merge.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


co<-matrix(NA, nrow=44, ncol = 7)

## Regression for mkt returns and 7 variables 
for (i in 5:44){
  cat(i)
  temp <- lm(ret~earningsyld+book2mkt+leverage+corptax+financials+Momentum+lnmktcap, na.action="na.omit", data = z[1000*(i-1)+1:1000*i,])
  co[i,]<- summary(temp)$coefficient [2:8,1]
}
```

Comment: Try using `cat(i)` in your loop to see which iteration your loop is on. Also, some potential errors: `naomit` should be quoted, and you have `ata` instead of what I imagine is meant to be `data`. You don't need to have `z$` in front of each variable in the formula. I can bet what's happening is that each regression is running the entire data set, which appears to be 40,000 rows. That'll take a while.

Comment: When you use a `data` argument, you don't need `z$` because `lm()` knows which data set you're drawing from. Because you wrote `ata` instead, `lm()` ignores that part and only sees `z$ret`, etc., which refers to the entire `ret` column in your dataset, not just the partition you want to analyze in each iteration.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So when I remove z$ I get the following message (Updated code abovee) "Error in co[i, ] <- summary(temp)$coefficent[2:8, 1] : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Comment: As was mentioned below, when you use indexing (i.e., `z[1000*(i-1)+1:1000*i,]`), you need to have parentheses around each side of the `:`. Hack-R's code for the data part should work. Sorry I missed this.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Built-in example data
data("mtcars")
mtcars <- rbind(mtcars,mtcars,mtcars,mtcars,mtcars,mtcars,
                mtcars,mtcars,mtcars,mtcars,mtcars)

# Let's pretend that instead of 1000 rows it's 10, so that I can use builtin data to show you

co<-matrix(NA, nrow=35, ncol = 1)

## Regressions 
for (i in 1:floor(nrow(mtcars)/10)){
  cat(i)
  temp   <- lm(mpg~cyl, na.action="na.omit", data = mtcars[((i-1)*10)+1:(i*10),])
  co[i,] <- summary(temp)$coefficients[2:2,1]
}

head(co)
```

> ```
>           [,1]
> [1,] -1.696939
> [2,] -3.461047
> [3,] -2.572180
> [4,] -2.651129
> [5,] -3.023638
> [6,] -2.712391
> ```

I believe there was a problem with your indexing as well as an incorrect spelling of the `coefficients` element of the summary object. Any other issues would be data issues, so if you still have problems after this be sure to provide the data.

For example if a problem in the data (singularity, all missing values, no identifying variation, etc) causes the inestimitability of a coefficient then it will change the size of the returned summary and break your loop. The only solution to that would be to clean your data or change your model to avoid using bad data.

Comment: Thanks. I am incredibly new to R (Just started coding a couple of hours ago). I have modified the code as per your feedback. Essentially I would like to have an output where I could get the coefficients for each of the iterations for each of the independent variables in one table. Headers preferably would be the independent variable coefficients. I have added a link to the data set in the original statement. Thank you for your help!